# transforming an array of objects into a new object

Tags: javascript

The following code is working OK, giving the desired output, but I'm wondering if there's a more concise way to achieve the end result.  Specifically, is there an approach that eliminates declaring `const consolidated = {};`?  Maybe `Object.assign()` has potential...?

```
const forecast = [
    { productId: 111, bucket: '2021-05-01', quantity: 3500 },
    { productId: 111, bucket: '2021-06-01', quantity: 3600 },
    { productId: 111, bucket: '2021-07-01', quantity: 4100 },
    { productId: 111, bucket: '2021-08-01', quantity: 4000 },
    { productId: 111, bucket: '2021-09-01', quantity: 3800 }
];

const consolidated = {};

forecast.forEach(o => {
    consolidated[o.bucket] = o.quantity
});

console.log('consolidated', consolidated);
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: For working code you should ask in [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), not in stackoverflow

Comment: Please include output as text, not as a picture of text. You can use `console.log(JSON.stringify(consolidated, null, 2))` in this case to get a prettified output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a single step with `Object.fromEntries`:

```
const consolidated = Object.fromEntries(
  forecast.map(o => [o.bucket, o.quantity])
);
```

But `Object.fromEntries` is a somewhat new method - obsolete browsers don't understand it, so make sure to include a polyfill (which you should probably already be doing if this is a professional project).

Answer (score 1):

#### Using `Array#reduce`

```js
const 
  forecast = [{productId:111,bucket:"2021-05-01",quantity:3500},{productId:111,bucket:"2021-06-01",quantity:3600},{productId:111,bucket:"2021-07-01",quantity:4100},{productId:111,bucket:"2021-08-01",quantity:4e3},{productId:111,bucket:"2021-09-01",quantity:3800}],

  res = forecast.reduce(
    (res, { bucket, quantity }) => ((res[bucket] = quantity), res), {}
  );

console.log(res);
```

#### Another Solution

**NOTE:** This will create new objects again and again.

```js
const 
  forecast = [{productId:111,bucket:"2021-05-01",quantity:3500},{productId:111,bucket:"2021-06-01",quantity:3600},{productId:111,bucket:"2021-07-01",quantity:4100},{productId:111,bucket:"2021-08-01",quantity:4e3},{productId:111,bucket:"2021-09-01",quantity:3800}],

  res = forecast.reduce(
    (res, { bucket, quantity }) => ({ ...res, [bucket]: quantity }), {}
  );

console.log(res);
```